# Can the preposition "to" be immediately followed by a "that + Subject +Verb + Object" clause?

Tags: clauses

I was trying to proof read an article about USA/Philippines trade with the following paragraph:

> The statistics of 2016 help us predict the future of fastener business
>   between the USA and Philippines. According to the statistics, the Philippines business in November 2016
>   has not been affected, and *it can be translated **to that the U.S. and
>   Philippines continue their relationship as before***.

I wanted to correct it to *"it can be translated to **the fact** that the U.S. and Philippines continue their relationship as before"*, or *"it can be translated to **a situation where** the U.S. and Philippines continue their relationship as before"* but I'm not sure if the author of this paragraph was grammatically correct in the first place.

Could anyone tell me whether I'm right to correct it or how should I correct it if need be?

Comment: Where did you find article? From what I learned, *that*-clause cannot be a complement of a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is that the clause in bold refers to another way to say what is being written about (sort of translated in meaning rather than language).

> The statistics of 2016 help us predict the future of fastener business between the USA and Philippines. According to the statistics, **the Philippines business in November 2016 has not been affected**, and it can be translated to 'that the U.S. and Philippines **continue their relationship** as before'.

"continuing the relationship" having the same intent as "the Philippines business ... has not been affected".